# libstableR doesn't build for macOS

Tags: r

I would like to use the R package libstableR on a mac.  I'm not a contributor/author of the package and have contacted them regarding [libstableR failing for osx](https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_libstableR.html):

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/4581196/28551755-0653b426-70b8-11e7-978f-cc9b1e5e039a.png]

After contacting the authors who said the problem is probably related to R not knowing where GSL is on the computer, I applied [two minor edits to
the DESCRIPTION and the src/Makevars](https://github.com/swihart/libstableR/commit/db0d26f03fd1ae40376133b0d230534db374fe6e) in addition to requiring the mac user to do the following:

1. be sure to have [homebrew](https://brew.sh/)
2. be sure to have [gsl](http://www2.lawrence.edu/fast/GREGGJ/CMSC210/gsl/gsl.html)
3. be sure to have Rcpp and [RcppGSL](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppGSL/vignettes/RcppGSL-intro.pdf): just `install.packages("RcppGSL")` in R

Sources:

[Dirk Eddelbuettel answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39153194/2727349)

[GREGGJ website on homebrew installing GSL on macs](http://www2.lawrence.edu/fast/GREGGJ/CMSC210/gsl/gsl.html)

Applying the steps above has changed the output of

```
devtools::install_github("swihart/libstableR")
```

From:

```
<SNIP>
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘libstableR’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Users/swihartbj/RLIB/libstableR/libs/libstableR.so':
  dlopen(/Users/swihartbj/RLIB/libstableR/libs/libstableR.so, 6): Symbol not found: _stable_set_THREADS
  Referenced from: /Users/swihartbj/RLIB/libstableR/libs/libstableR.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/swihartbj/RLIB/libstableR/libs/libstableR.so
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Users/swihartbj/RLIB/libstableR’
```

to:

```
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘libstableR’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Users/swihartbj/RLIB/libstableR/libs/libstableR.so':
  dlopen(/Users/swihartbj/RLIB/libstableR/libs/libstableR.so, 6): Symbol not found: _libstableR_stable_cdf
  Referenced from: /Users/swihartbj/RLIB/libstableR/libs/libstableR.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/swihartbj/RLIB/libstableR/libs/libstableR.so
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Users/swihartbj/RLIB/libstableR’
```

Where basically instead of complaining about `_stable_set_THREADS` the errors pertain to `_libstableR_stable_cdf`. `libstableR_stable_cdf` is an exported function. The leading underscore in `_libstableR_stable_cdf` is put there when Roxygen/Rcpp is applied.

I have tinkered and online searched for about two months trying to get this up and running, and now come to SO for help.

Anyway to get libstableR working on a mac?

Comment: Hey Bruce. See if https://github.com/swihart/libstableR/pull/2 works for you. I can chat abt it later this week.

Comment: Works!  If you want some internet points, make it an answer.  ;-)  You have my deepest gratitude already!  If you contact maintainers, feel free to cc me.

Comment: lemme post more of a "what i did to fix" type of answer. that might be helpful to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I went to https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/libstableR/index.html and grabbed https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/libstableR_1.0.tar.gz (I knew Bruce had a repo but I wanted to see the original).

I had `gsl` (homebrew) and the `RcppGSL` installed already.

I did a quick `devtools::document()` since I figured it used Rcpp everywhere and got:

```
Error in dyn.load(dllfile) :
  unable to load shared object '/private/tmp/libstableR/src/libstableR.so':
  dlopen(/private/tmp/libstableR/src/libstableR.so, 6): Symbol not found: _libstableR_stable_cdf
  Referenced from: /private/tmp/libstableR/src/libstableR.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /private/tmp/libstableR/src/libstableR.so
```

There were two definitions (one Rcpp exposed and one internal) for `stable_cdf()` so I made the internal one `int_stable_cdf()` and made the change to the singular call to it.

I still got a similar error so I suspected they hand-crafted some things.

I went in and made the NAMESPACE auto-generate from roxygen comments and added `//' @export`s for the key exposed functions.

I removed `init.c` since Rcpp auto-gen's registration code now.

I *still* got an error, but this time for `stable_set_THREADS` being unavailable.

It turns out they really don't care abt macOS folks at all:

```
#ifdef __WIN32
void stable_set_THREADS(unsigned int value) {
/*
  SYSTEM_INFO sysinfo;
  GetSystemInfo(&sysinfo);
  THREADS = (unsigned int)sysinfo.dwNumberOfProcessors;
  */

  THREADS = 12;
}
#else
#ifdef __unix
void stable_set_THREADS(unsigned int value) {
  if (value == 0) THREADS = sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);
  else THREADS = value;
  //printf("\nCPUs = %u\n",THREADS);
}
#endif
#endif
```

I removed the `unix` `ifdef`, tweaked a few more incidentals and it works.

I'll see if we can get this on GH and get the maintainers to OK some further tweaks to make it easier for others to contribute.